# WCF WiX deployed app Commands not functioning

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WCF application that I have built and deployed using WiX.  In my development environment, the application runs fine.  When I attempt to launch the app after installation on a test machine, the app launches fine, but no 'buttons' work.

(I quoted buttons because I have an actual button and a pair of menu items that will not work.)

I am using an MVVM pattern and all of the buttons use Commands.  I have set the Datacontext to be an instance of the ViewModel where the command methods are stored.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public MainWindow(Configuration config)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        log.Info("Application started.");
        MainWindowViewModel _model = new MainWindowViewModel(config);
        _model.Config = config;
        DataContext = _model;
        Closing += _model.OnClosing;
    }
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public MainWindowViewModel(Configuration config)
    {
        try
        {
            Config = config;

            ...

            PlayCommand = new PlayCommand(this);
            StopCommand = new StopCommand(this);
            PauseCommand = new PauseCommand(this);
            OptionsCommand = new OptionsCommand(this);
            ExitCommand = new ExitCommand(this);

            ...

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }


public void Play()
    {
        <Play logic>
    }
```

PlayCommand.cs

```
public class PlayCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public PlayCommand(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _viewModel.IsPlaying;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.Play();
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Use Snoop and examine the bindings at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the log - there is probably an exception being thrown before any of the commands are initialized.

Seeing as how it occurs only on the test machine, my guess is it is loading a file that isn't there or some other system/environmental issue. If the application can run even if that exception occurs, make the try-catch block wrap a smaller more relevant part of the code and let the buttons initialize.  If the application shouldn't run when that exception is thrown, you can display a message or something similar and exit.